# How to move text on next line by center?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

```
 <Label paddingTop="10" textWrap="true" text="Maxim Savelov"
horizontalAlignment="center"></Label>
```

It gives me the following result:

```
Maxim
Savelov
```

But I need this:

```
 Maxim
Savelov
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS property for text alignment works here.

```
<Label style="text-align: center; padding-top: 10" textWrap="true" text="Maxim Savelov"></Label>
```